# What jQuery plugin will do this Wordpress-like effect?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, minimize

I'm wondering if anyone knows what jQuery plugin can do the effects WordPress has for its heading boxes. That is, when you first login you have boxes like "Right Now", "Quick Press", etc. When you hover over the heading, an arrow appears and you can minimize this. I don't know if they do this with jQuery, but if so: what plugin do they use? If not, what jQuery plugin will do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Slicker Show and Hide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide):

> Last time I showed you how to make
>   something appear and disappear on a
>   web page. This time I'll show you how
>   to do it with style.